# Allocate memory for a pointer to vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, malloc

I have a structure PWS:

```
struct PWS{
    uint64_t key;
    char* value;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint64_t txn_id;
};
```

I want to create a pointer to a vector of PWS to populate it later in my code. Is this way correct?

```
int total_no_of_items = 100000;
vector<PWS> * pws = (vector<PWS>*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(vector<PWS>*) * total_no_of_items, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is incorrect. You are allocating 100000 uninitialized **pointers** to `vector<PWS>`, not a vector of structs. If you want to allocate a vector of structs that would be as simple as:

```
vector<PWS> pws(total_no_of_items);
```

If you want the vector itself be heap-allocate (for whatever strange reason), then that would be:

```
unique_ptr<vector<PWS>> pws(new vector<PWS>(total_no_of_items));
```

Also it's unclear why you're trying to use `_mm_malloc`. If your goal is to load your struct with some SIMD instructions, then you should specify the alignment on the struct:

```
struct alignas(16) PWS { ... }; // aligned for xmm
```

`std::vector`'s allocator will take care of the rest.